# Nativescript No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'

Tags: nativescript

When I try to compile with Nativescript `3.3.1` and the latest tns-android I receive the error `No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'`.

I've tried upgrading nativescript CLI to next development release and tns-android to next development release but this issue persists. I've also tried modifying my app.gradle to something along the lines below:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
}

android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = "org.nativescript.Audible"
  }  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors" 
  }  
} 

ext {
  complieSdkVersion = 26  
  buildToolsVersion = "26.0.1"
}
```

But nothing has worked so far. What is the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by using the following app.gradle:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = "org.nativescript.HelloWorld"
  }  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors" 
  }  
}
```

Comment: This is correct but I had to do a few other things to get it working after.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}
```

To the app.gradle file in app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle

Once you do that you might have to accept the licenses and download Android API 26 packages even if you have already downloaded most of API 26 before. Check "Show Package Details" in the Android SDK tools to prompt you to download and accept API 26 packages.

After that if its still telling you you need to accept the license
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle

That link will help you out. Here is a copy from that link that helped me finally fix the issue.

> If you have accepted the license agreements on one workstation, but wish to build your projects on a different one, you can export your licenses by copying over the accepted licenses directory. To copy the licenses to another machine, follow these steps:
>
> On a machine with Android Studio installed, click Tools > Android > SDK Manager. At the top of the window, note the Android SDK Location.
> Navigate to that directory and locate the licenses/ directory inside it. (If you do not see a licenses/ directory, return to Android Studio and update your SDK tools, making sure to accept the license agreements. When you return to the Android SDK home directory, you should now see the directory.)
> Copy the entire licenses/ directory and paste it into the Android SDK home directory on the machine where you wish to build your projects.
> Gradle will now be able to automatically download missing packages your project depends on.